# Login in iCloud with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, icloud

Hello i need help on my robot. i'm tring to login on iCloud with selenium but in this page.
[Trust computer iCloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTGPk.png)

i cannot found anything, because id, xpath and others way to find this button is dinamic só i cannot do this

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="not-now-trust-1681754050999-0"]'))).click()

i'm using Python to do this.
Somw one know something about ??

i'm try to loggin on icloud with selenium

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, get the element by anything other than the dynamic ID, for example the not-now-btn class.

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button.not-now-btn'))).click()
```